# API response data array count is lesser than actual count in Rest Assured Java

Tags: java, rest-assured

I need to count the API response data array. Below is the code for the count of the array.

```
ArrayList<Map<String,Object>> jsonList = response.jsonPath().get("data");
         int i =  jsonList.get(0).size();

        System.out.println("Data Count in response : " +i);
```

The response of the API is below

```
{
    "response": {
        "code": 200,
        "status": "success",
        "alert": [
            {
                "message": "Success",
                "type": "success",
                "skippable": 1
            }
        ],
        "from_cache": 0,
        "is_data": 1
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "airport_name": "London Luton Airport",
            "city": "London",
            "country": "United Kingdom",

        },
        {
            "airport_name": "London Biggin Hill Airport",
            "city": "Biggin Hill",
            "country": "United Kingdom",

        },
]
}
```

We have to count the number of the Data array in response. Currently getting wrong count.

Comment: Are you getting the JSON list? because what I see is data is an array of object and ArrayList<Map<String,Object>> jsonList = response.jsonPath().get("data"); you are storing that in map? try Array of object only

Comment: Yes, I am getting the arraylist perfectly, both Postman and Json arraylist values are same but only the count value are less. In Postman and Response arraylist count is 10 but   int i =  jsonList.get(0).size(); only gives 8.

Comment: {country=United Kingdom, airport_name=London Luton Airport} is the json list , total 10 values displays

Comment: see I need to know whether you are trying to count the keys?                               
  jsonList.get(0)  ->  gives the first key Object as per you attached the response in comment. Also, its a map, what are you trying to count. Please attach a snapshot of the JSON list you getting while debugging.

Comment: just check I have updated the response , now we need to count how many set of array records display in response data, like data now contains two set of records, so on.....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206767/discussion-between-vipin-singh-and-ayushi-keshri).

Comment: try jsonList.size();

Comment: Thanks, done, we don't need to get(0) part, it works.

Comment: If you have a working solution, please post it as an answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Try below instead of map
ArrayList jsonList = response.jsonPath().get("data");

Comment: Display the same count

Comment: can you share complete json

Comment: just check the I have updated the response with more data set.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Object> jsonList = js1.getList("data");

    System.out.println("Data Count in response : " + jsonList.size());
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality: make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem.
It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also Explaining entirely code-based answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers

Answer (score 0):

Below code is working for me 
ArrayList> jsonList = response.jsonPath().get("data");

```
     int i =  jsonList.size();
```